# python article scraping extract time form Article.publish_date

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

python web scraping, from published date how to extract time? 
EX: POSTED **2:42 PM, DECEMBER 30, 2013**, BY CNN WIRE

from above how to extract time **2:42 pm**

> python

```
from newspaper import Article
url = 'http://fox13now.com/2013/12/30/new-year-new-laws-obamacare-pot-guns-and-drones/'
article = Article(url)
article.download()
article.html
article.parse()
article.publish_date
article.nlp()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BeautifulSoup::

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

url = 'http://fox13now.com/2013/12/30/new-year-new-laws-obamacare-pot-guns-and-drones/'

temp = requests.get(url).text

temp=BeautifulSoup(temp, "lxml")
header = temp.find('div',{'class':"entry-meta clearfix"})
date = header.find('span').text


print(date)
```

Output:

```
Posted 2:42 pm, December 30, 2013, by CNN Wire
[Finished in 2.8s]
```